# Why does CppCheck flag static constexpr members as unusedStructMember, when it is used later in the struct definition

Tags: c++, c++17, static-analysis, cppcheck

CppCheck is flagging the definition of BufLen as an unusedStructMember, even though it is used on the next line to define the length of the array.

> (style) struct member 'TxDetails_t::BufLen' is never used. [unusedStructMember]

```
static struct TxDetails_t
{
    static constexpr int32_t BufLen = 128;  
    
    uint8_t buffer[BufLen];
    uint8_t* ptr;
    int32_t num_bytes;
    
} TxData;
```

Is CppCheck wrong to report this, or is there a better way for me to define this struct?

Comment: Try adding `inline` to the declaration.

Comment: @Spencer: Static constexpr members are implicitly inline.

Comment: sounds like something you should report to the authors of cppcheck

Comment: @NicolBolas Nevertheless, it would reduce the scope of the bug, if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a false positive and it is fixed in the upcoming Cppcheck 2.7. I can reproduce it with 2.6 but not with the latest head.

Looking at the list of fixed issues it appears you encountered https://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/10485.